# SIP сервер в локальной сети

Tags: сервер

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, а возможно ли поднять SIP сервер для звонков между компьютерами компании (естественно при наличие соответствующих программ на этих компах и аккаунтах на этом SIP сервере), не подключая при этом SIP к реальному номеру.И еще хотелось бы узнать, имеются ли OpenSource SIP серверы и где можно было бы их пощупать, так скажем, а то что-то я не нашел.Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Для звонка между компьютерами нет необходимости в SIP-сервере. Минимум 2 компьютера с программой [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/), чтобы позвонить можно просто указать IP-адрес терминатора. Никаких номеров.
2. Открытые соусы - это всегда прекрасно )))) в качестве SIP-сервера посмотри на [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/), говорят, что сильная штука.
3. Всегда пожалуйста, поржал от души (несмотря на это советы дельные)

Comment: Понятненько ) Соус исправлять не буду, пусть и другие поржут :)

Answer (score 1):

*а возможно ли поднять сип сервер для звонков между компьютерами компании (естественно при наличие соответствующих программ на этих компах и аккаунтах на этом сип сервере), не подключая при этом СИП к реальному номеру.*

Можно и не париться с собственым СИП-сервером, а ограничиться включением [виртуальной АТС](http://clck.ru/NpqJ) и будет понятно, и управлять очень удобно. По цене - практически даром...